# laravel losing URL parameters

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel project which needs to pass parameters in the URL, but if the user is logged in it loses the parameters because the user is redirect to the home page.

example the URL is like this:

`laravel.dev/login?color=blue&number=12`

But if the user is logged in it is redirect from /login to /home which is good but i need the parameters to be passed through on the redirect as well so will look like this:

`laravel.dev/home?color=blue&number=12`

Can someone please help me to define this.

Thanks in advance

[login function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb9DQ.jpg)

Comment: Are you using the Auth `login()` function or you have created you own login function?

Answer (score 2):

Cheers @info,

you could overwrite the function "sendLoginResponse(Request $request)" from the trait "Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers":

```
/**
 * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
            ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Open your **LoginController** (app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php) and add your overwriting function and add your get parameters to the redirect:

```
/**
 * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
            ?: redirect('/foo', ['color' => $request->get('color')]);
}
```

The code is not tested. Hope its an helpful inspiration

---

### Update - I've implemented my solution to a test project

At first I added the parameter color to my login form:
[image]
At the second step I overwrote the sendLoginResponse function in my LoginController. I had to change `redirect('/foo', ['color' => $request->get('color')])` to `redirect()->route('dashboard', ['color' => $request->get('color', 'white')])`:
[image]

And at the last step I debugged my code to see if the color GET parameter is transmitted to the overwritten function:
[image]

**Here is the result:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ive tried and i can add the parameters to redirects which i define.

however i cannot get it to work for the login, from what i can tell it has something to do with the csrf token, /login uses the csrf token and 302 redirects to /home losing the paramaters

Comment: Hey @info, I've updated my answer with the solution and some screenshots

Comment: Hey, i cant figure out where to do this, i have attached a picture of the function on the login page

Comment: You have to overwrite the function "sendLoginResponse" from the trait "Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers". Place the overwriting function "sendLoginResponse" into your LoginController -> "app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php"